# Nested for of loop inside multiple for loops typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm not sure if this is possible at all, but I would like to do the following. I have the Array of objects, and i want to generate some values from it like this:

```
const arr = [
  {
    type: "color",
    values: [
      {
        name: "Color",
        option: "Black",
      },
      {
        name: "Color",
        option: "Blue",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    type: "size",
    values: [
      {
        name: "Size",
        option: "XS",
      },
      {
        name: "Size",
        option: "M",
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

```
let oldArr: any[] = [];
if (arr.length === 1) {
  for (const iterator of arr[arr.length - 1].values) {
    oldArr.push(iterator);
  }
} else if (arr.length === 2) {
  for (const iterator of arr[arr.length - 1].values) {
    for (const iterator2 of arr[arr.length - 2].values) {
      oldArr.push([iterator, iterator2]);
    }
  }
} else if (arr.length === 3) {
  for (const iterator of arr[arr.length - 1].values) {
    for (const iterator2 of arr[arr.length - 2].values) {
      for (const iterator3 of arr[arr.length - 3].values) {
        oldArr.push([iterator, iterator2, iterator3]);
      }
    }
  }
} else if (arr.length === 4) {
  for (const iterator of arr[arr.length - 1].values) {
    for (const iterator2 of arr[arr.length - 2].values) {
      for (const iterator3 of arr[arr.length - 3].values) {
        for (const iterator4 of arr[arr.length - 4].values) {
          oldArr.push([iterator, iterator2, iterator3, iterator4]);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

There is possible to do that in recursive mode N times?
Added real Array of objects...

Expected Output that i need is an array of array:

```js
 const oldArr = [

[
    {
        "name" : "Color", 
        "option" : "Blue", 
    }, 
    {
        "name" : "Size", 
        "option" : "XS"
    }
],
[
    {
        "name" : "Color", 
        "option" : "Black", 
    }, 
    {
        "name" : "Size", 
        "option" : "XS"
    }
],
[
    {
        "name" : "Color", 
        "option" : "Blue", 
    }, 
    {
        "name" : "Size", 
        "option" : "M"
    }
],
[
    {
        "name" : "Color", 
        "option" : "Black", 
    }, 
    {
        "name" : "Size", 
        "option" : "M"
    }
]
]
```

What detail i must to add before posting this?

Comment: Sounds like a good candidate for recursion.

Comment: Yes, Working  like a charm! I want to generate variation from diferent type of product! Like woocomerce variations! Just edited a post, i forgot to rename result!

Comment: TLDR: This kind of branching/looping/nesting is a [code smell](https://www.techtarget.com/searchsoftwarequality/tip/Understanding-code-smells-and-how-refactoring-can-help#:~:text=Put%20simply%2C%20code%20smells%20are,in%20accordance%20with%20necessary%20standards.) in need of refactoring.

Comment: It's possible and looks like it is called a cartesian product of arrays. Can you please give an example for the input and expected output?

Comment: Added real Array of objects...

Comment: @RuslanJackson I have updated my code to work with the example you gave. Please let me know if this is not the output you are expecting or if you want some other change made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of a recursive function that should achieve your results. I have tested it for inputs up to 4 nested loops and it seems to work. The arguments are mostly self explanatory, `arr` is the array you are reading, `oldArr` is the array you are writing to, `vals` is a list used for keeping track of all the iterator values (you should pass an empty list to start!), `level` is the "level of recursion" and `target_level` is the final level of recursion you want. An example of how to run this might be `recursive_func(arr, oldArr, [], 1, 4)` if you want to achieve the same result as your 4 nested loop example.

If the number of nested `for` loops is always the same as the length of `arr` please let me know so that the function can be slightly simplified.

```js
function recursive_func(arr, oldArr, vals, level, target_level) {
    for (const it_n of arr[arr.length - level].values) {
        vals.push(it_n);
        if (level == target_level) {
            oldArr.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(vals)));
        } else {
            recursive_func(arr, oldArr, vals, level + 1, target_level);
        }
         vals.pop()
    }
}

const arr = [
  {
    type: "color",
    values: [
      {
        name: "Color",
        option: "Black",
      },
      {
        name: "Color",
        option: "Blue",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    type: "size",
    values: [
      {
        name: "Size",
        option: "XS",
      },
      {
        name: "Size",
        option: "M",
      },
    ],
  },
];
let oldArr = [];
recursive_func(arr, oldArr, [], 1, arr.length);

console.log(oldArr);
```

Comment: Thx, this version is working at 99%! When arr length is === 1, must return a single array inside another array, not array of single object! But this is not a problem, now, i can edit this function! Thx!